# Facebook sharer.php redirect url

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-share

I'm using Facebook sharing using sharer.php redirection.
Upon clicking on share button, i'm redirecting to

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://google.com
```

It opens the proper sharing page. But how do i redirect back to another url after share or cancel ? Can't find the apt parameter.

P.S. - I know this method for sharing has been deprecated, but for some reason i would like to use this method.

Comment: I am not sure if this particular one ever had a such a parameter ... For the current version of the Share _dialog_ that’s no problem, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog#redirect

Comment: Don't want to use share dialog, want this method only.